# Is it possible to let IAM user to run aws-cli without permanent access key on my PC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I just want to run aws-cli or my application(using aws sdk) on my PC, not on aws services, under privileges of my IAM user. In this case, do I have to store permanent accesskey/secretkey associated my IAM user on my PC?

I want to use only temporary access key using `assume_role`, but I think I need a permanent access key to call `assume_role` in programatic access. Focusing on security, there seems no pros to go this way (unless forced MFA).
Am I correct? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want the PC to have permanent access, that means you want the user to provide some kind of *secret* to prove his identity and call `assume_role`, as and when he needs the access. There are few options I can think of.

**MFA**

As you rightly pointed out, in this case, the *secret* can be an MFA PIN, and you force MFA so that no actions are allowed unless user is authenticated with MFA. This way, even if you store the accesskey/secretkey, they mean nothing without the MFA.

**Console**

The other method of providing *secret* is, of course, going to console and entering your password. Then generate accesskey/secretkey from IAM, and do what you need to do. Then, revoke the keys once done.

**Encryption**

If on the other hand you don't mind having permanent access, you can just encrypt the accesskey/secretkey file. For example, zip your aws credentials file with password. Unlock it whenever you need, and delete it again when done.

**Final Remarks**

As there is no escaping the need to provide some form of *secret*, I think this step is unavoidable. And from the examples above, MFA sounds like the most convenient and secure method to me.

Answer (score 1):

Use AWS SSO to manage users. Then users could login to aws cli by typing 'aws sso login' which opens a web browser and starts auth flow. This method does not require that secrets are installed locally.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-sso.html

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at AWS STS (Simple Token Service). https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/welcome.html

This service creates temporary security credentials along with session token and once the session expires, these keys are useless. This is much better than hardcoding any keys anywhere.

Follow the documentation to use STS from CLI. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_use-resources.html#using-temp-creds-sdk-cli

Comment: This solution requires anyway logging in by using SSO or IAM credentials and does not solve the original problem.